# Base table or view not found: 1146 after new extension install

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

I've installed a new extension using the steps below to ensure everything goes in  desired sequence

1. Ensured 'compilation' is disabled
2. Enabled cache
3. Copied all files
4. After that, did cache refresh
5. // Received  404 error on extension tab
6. Logged out & logged in to admin
7. Extension settings showed fine

**But** on front-end -- it's throwing an error & report shows the following

`a:5:{i:0;s:217:"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento.affiliateplus_account' doesn't exist`

I've disabled the extension for now

How can I resolve this issue?
Any pointers?

Comment: What is the solution ? can you please give me an update?

Comment: Is your error related to `affiliateplus_account` table?

Answer (score 2):

It seems the extension has to create one table `affiliateplus_account` but some how it couldn't.

So this way you can proceed.

- Check sql folder in your extension module. There must be query to create table.
- Now run this query direct in your mysql.